# SQL server Credit/Debit Balance query

Tags: sql, duplicates

I would like to get the first row from the below  sql table. The other four rows are got balanced with the credit/debit. Any help is appreciated.

Sql table Input

---

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your description and your sample just don't connect.  Why is the first row removed if you want *unique* rows.

Comment: Echoing Gordon, all of your input rows are unique already. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, could you explain the logic a bit better?

Comment: Updated the input table